# Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c “rm ./mean/package.json”

Tags: meanjs, yo

How to fix this error. When i use command “yo meanjs”, but not show as in video. It’s:
undefined
You’re using the official MEAN.JS generator.
What mean,js version would you like to generate? i choose 0.4.0
In which filder would you like the project to be generated? mean
Cloning the MEAN repo…
Then it appear error:
Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c “rm ./mean/package.json”
‘rm’ is not recognized as an internal and external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: That error is being addressed in MEAN.js github repo [here](https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/issues/118).

Comment: but the problem has not been resolved

Answer (score 2):

you should install **git on windown 7** and select **folder you want** . click -> **right mouse** -> **Git Bash**
After type command : **"yo meanjs"** and everything will good

Comment: Thanks.. that worked for me.  But why does it work in the Bash?  And not powershell?  Any ideas?

Comment: actually, I spoke too soon.. it got farther in the process but still produced the same error.

Comment: The reason not working with the normal Bash is that it also requires git command, git.exe. You need to include a path for git.exe.

Answer (score 0):

The [tpt2213's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32654270/3239341) works, but it can't select menu items of "yo meanjs" with arrow keys.
You need to have cmd.exe with PATH setting, which includes the git command and Unix commands like the rm.

If you install **git on window 7** in the folder, "C:\Program Files\Git", set PATH before you run "yo meanjs".

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%
yo meanjs
```