# Yeoman not able to install MEAN.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, yeoman, mean-stack

I followed [this](http://www.bossable.com/303/install-mean-stack/) tutorial to start with mean stack development. But getting following error:

```
    C:\My_Path>yo meanjs
    undefined
    You're using the official MEAN.JS generator.
    ? What mean.js version would you like to generate? (Use arrow keys)
    ? What mean.js version would you like to generate? 0.4.0
    0.4.0
    ? In which folder would you like the project to be generated? This can be changed later. mean
    Cloning the MEAN repo.......
    Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "rm ./mean/package.json
    "
    'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

    F:\>yo --version
    1.5.0

    F:\>npm --version
    3.3.12
```

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634504/error-command-failed-c-windows-system32-cmd-exe-s-c-rm-mean-package-json) here not working for me.

Comment: This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/issues/121) for the generator.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski is right, it is a known issue.    The tutorials on Bossable are great.. its a great site and great tutorial.  In addition, Mean.js is great but there are lot of moving parts and you can get bogged down instead of learning.  I find this walkthrough works well to start with. http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/